# Ability to lock documentation topics (as for questions)

Tags: feature-request, documentation

It would be nice at some point to be able to lock certain topic to prevent changes from users with low reputation, as it already happens for certain questions.

The reason is that basic topics tends to attract very low quality edits. In most cases, these edits tends to duplicate other examples, whereas the examples were previously split on purpose to avoid one giant piece of information.

Increasing the difficulty to edit essential or high quality topics (especially given how frequently they may likely be linked from Q&A) will guarantee that the quality of the contribution is preserved.

Another option could be to be able to lock examples rather than topics. In this way, we don't close the possibility to contribute with new information, but we avoid altering quality examples with low quality contributions.

Unfortunately, the review process is not always helpful here as it looks like several contributions were approved by possibly unexperienced developers, that did not pay a lot attention to the approved code (sometimes the code was not even formatted or working, still it passed 2 approvals).